# General rule of a $k-$form wedge product with itself over the real numbers

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Is it true that, for a $k-$form $\alpha$, $\alpha\wedge\alpha$ is always $0$ if $k$ is odd; and not always $0$ if $k$ is even?

My reason is that, for basic $k-$forms $dx_I,dx_J$, we have $dx_J\wedge dx_I=(-1)^{k^2}dx_I\wedge dx_J$, so, if $k$ is odd, they always cancel out each other.

Comment: Are you working over the real numbers? Your argument shows that $\alpha\wedge\alpha=-\alpha\wedge\alpha$ if $\alpha$ is a $k$-form, $k$ odd. This is to say that $2\alpha\wedge\alpha=0$. Over a field of characteristic not $2$, this implies $\alpha\wedge\alpha=0$, but over a field of a characteristic $2$, you can have $\alpha\wedge\alpha\neq0$.

Comment: @Thorgott Oh yeah, over the real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is always true. The [wedge product](https://math.wikia.org/wiki/Wedge_product#:%7E:text=The%20Wedge%20product%20is%20the,wedge%20product%20is%20defined%20as) is indeed a generalization of the vector product, and the vector product of the same vector is easily seen to be always zero. Like the cross product, the exterior product is anticommutative, meaning that $ u \wedge v=-(v \wedge u)$ for all vectors $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Thank you! The page you mentioned is interesting. I've never seen calculating wedge product using cross product.

Comment: Happy to help! :)